What is a proper word for (almost) identical products?
In my language we say "these products are analogues (of each other)" meaning they are similar to be point of being identical. For example, when procuring equipment, one may argue that we can use another product as it is a complete analogue of the one originally proposed, as it has 100% identical specifications. The key point here is that one can be used instead of the other, it will fit and still function as required.
How do I correcly express this idea in English? Can I refer to such products as "analogues"? I'm talking mainly about all kinds of equipment (pumps, seals, motherboards, fire hydrants, etc.)

The usual word is "equivalent" (n. and adj.)
MW

Adj. 3: corresponding or virtually identical especially in effect or
function.
"Those less-known companies manufacture equivalent products at cheaper prices."
(Noun) "Marjorie's kindness pleases him so much that he feels joy is an
equivalent of health." (New Yorker)

(It is possible to use "analogue" in English
OED analogue

II.General senses. II.6. A thing which (or occasionally person who) is
analogous to another; a parallel, an equivalent.
2007 Perhaps a cognitive analogue to cosmetic surgery will
emerge—instead of a face-lift, a ‘brain-lift’. New York Times Magazine
6 May 38/1

However, this meaning is generally used for the more abstract rather than concrete as "analogue" (adj.) is more associated as being the converse of "digital".)

Thanks! I forgot about "equivalent") I guess it will fit perfectly in certain contexts

@Mike Deserves an upvote if not an 'accepted answer' (though I'd hold on a day say before accepting to see what else is offered).

The opposite of digital is analog (no "ue" at the end).

@Barmar https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogue

@Greybeard Where does that definition mention digital? It does have a link to "analogue computer", but the entry only says it's a variant spelling. Is that common in BrE?

@Barmar - “analogue” is the preferred British English spelling, even in the field of electronics and computing.  Almost all words derived from the Ancient Greek with the tail -λογος are spelled -logue in British English. (see also “epilogue”, “monologue”, “travelogue”, “prologue”...).

@KrisW For some reason, in computing/engineering Americans tend to drop the "ue", but it's retained in most other contexts. So "analog computer" and "Prolog programming language" (although in that case it's also because "log" refers to "logic", it's a homonym of "prologue").

@Barmar - yes, although the name Prolog is actually French: “Programmation en Logique”, as the language was first developed at Aix-Marseille Université in France in the early 1970s. The French word prologue has the same meaning as in English, though, so the pun still works.

I agree with Barmar: analog is an adjective meaning "not digital" while analogue is a noun meaning "a parallel or equivalent". The two are different words, not alternate spellings of the same word.

From a technical/manufacturing perspective, a common term which seems apt here would be "interchangeable".
(Cambridge Dictionary):

able to be exchanged with each other without making any difference or without being noticed:

interchangeable parts



A similar word for a similar setting is interoperable - meaning that two things may be used by the same systems without requiring changes. (e.g. iPhone chargers produced by Apple and iPhone chargers produced by other companies are interoperable)

Yes, we use this as a technical term at work.

The term "substitute" could be used.
(Cambridge Dictionary) substitute
noun [ C ]

a thing or person that is used instead of another thing or person:

Tofu can be used as a meat substitute in vegetarian recipes.
substitute for Vitamins should not be used as a substitute for a healthy diet.


Merriam-Webster

substitute noun
: a person or thing that takes the place or function of another


substitute adjective


Specifically, in procurement, logistics, transportation, and subcontracting personnel, the term is "suitable substitute". It is usually defined in contracts; and the definition varies slightly from industry to industry. For instance, a suitable substitute rental car can not be more than one year older than the promised one, and must have the same or better features and trim level.

Yes, tofu and meat are not 'similar to be point of being [near-]identical'.

Fungible could be the word you're after.

adjective (of goods or commodities) freely exchangeable for or replaceable by another of like nature or kind in the satisfaction of an obligation


noun a commodity that is freely interchangeable with another in satisfying an obligation

[Vocabulary.com]

In The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary, this word, as a noun, is labelled "Law (Chiefly Scottish)"; as an adjective, it is labelled "Chiefly Law", although the definition is much  as in your answer: "Precisely or acceptably replacing or replaceable by another item, mutually interchangeable: esp. of goods etc. contracted for, when a particular item is not specified.". Could you add the name of your dictionary, verify that there is no indication of restricted usage for this entry, and as well  mention the part of speech?

@LPH I think it's a fairly common word(mostly encountered in economics I believe). I'd to check Merriam-Webster  for its law-related meaning.

It is not considered as restricted to the law in all dictionaries, but Dictionary.com mentions "Law, Commerce". The Cambridge dictionary also mentions "FINANCE & ECONOMICS".

It seems that this term (fungible) is too general; there is in it the notion of equal value but not that of equally usable for the same function (as the OP explains "The key point here is that one can be used instead of the other, it will fit and still function as required.").

Fungible (adj., n.) is wrong. The meaning is interchangeable as an acceptable option, e.g. "I can pay you by cash, cheque, or by shares in the company" - these three fungible items, although of the same value and utility, bear no physical relationship to one another, i.e. they are not identical in the way that the OP stipulates they must be. 1917 Economic goods, as distinct from money, are not generally ‘fungible’. B. M. Anderson, Value of Money vii. 134.

@Greybeard Thank you for your inputs. But according to Dictionary.com, the word also means  interchangeable in the sense I've answered. The dictionary has this example sentence for this sense of the word:
"Neither ethanol nor biodiesel is fully fungible with petroleum-based fuels." So I think fungible is a possibility.

@user405662 - without context, that quote is perhaps misleading - how do we know that the reference is not to trading on the petroleum market?

I'm good with fungible. A typical context is if you lent someone a dollar last week, and they give it back to you today. Almost certainly they won't return to you the same note or coin you originally handed over. But one dollar is fungible with another - for most purposes, that's true even if one is a banknote and the other is a coin. But note/coin aren't always fungible - if you lent someone a dollar in coin to use in a vending machine, and now you want it back to use that vending machine yourself, you certainly wouldn't accept repayment by banknote as "fungible".

fungible is an economics term, not a term for physical substitutes as in one thing is the same thing as another.

Is @FumbleFingers a Fungible Smerf? (anag.)

@Lambie: Fungibility and the quantum multiverse (David Deutsch, 2011) is hardly a treatise on economics!

Note too that currency bills and coins when viewed as collectibles (and postal stamps) may not be fungible items though that can still be tradeable with individual values differing from their face value.

When one manufacturer copies another's product (typically with enough superficial changes to avoid legal charges of forgery or violation of a patent or copyright), its product is often called a copycat version.

Also knockoff

Clone could also work.

“copycat”, and the suggestions in comments all have strong negative connotations.  The OP wanted a value-neutral word.

Another way to say that it doesn't matter whether you use one manufacturer's piece of equipment or another's inasmuch as they both adhere to an established specification, is to refer to them as generic parts.

These are both generic parts.


Defining a generic part is where designers specify the required parameters a part must have instead of an MPN. This is usually useful for passive components and common connectors where there are many different parts that satisfy the required properties. A generic resistor, for example, could be defined by its required parameters, “220Ω 0603 1% 0.125W”, meaning that any resistor that meets these specific requirements is acceptable, ignoring other ones such as temperature coefficient or specific manufacturer (although the assembler may take these into account for manufacturability). [https://www.eurocircuits.com/blog/the-power-of-generic-parts/]


"Generic" is also used in the context of pharmaceutical drugs. Once a chemical substance's patent has expired, other manufacturers are free to make their own versions that might be virtually identical to the original. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_drug

Ah, I didn't see your comment -- I have made that an answer.

There is a more specific term than what the above answers provide, and that is "alternative part", which applies to the domain of machinery, but this seems to be what the OP calls for.

(Arena)
Alternative Part
Definition
An alternative part is a replacement or substitute for a specific part or piece of machinery. Alternative parts are typically used when the original part is unavailable or has been discontinued. They can also offer better functionality at a lower price. Alternative parts may serve as a temporary fix while waiting for the original part to arrive or as a long-term fix.
Alternative parts are used in the context of production or maintenance to keep machinery operating in the event of a failure or breakdown. They help to modernize or enhance the functionality of equipment and make it more compatible with other parts or systems.

This reference tends to show that no single-word term exists.

I hate to disagree with your final sentence, but imho your preceding sentence provides the exact word OP is looking for - compatible. Defined in the full OED as both an adjective and a noun. The noun definition (Computing, 1972–) is Hardware or software that is usable on or with a specified piece of equipment or software, esp. without adaptation or modification. Frequently with distinguishing word.

@FumbleFingers I agree with the fact that compatibility is the central idea in this concept, but it is not sufficient: the realm of entities that can be called compatible is vast, ranging from mere facts to all sorts of devices not forgetting people, who can be psychologically compatible with one another or not; therefore there is a missing concept and as, roughly speaking, the OP is concerned with machinery and a single word, the adjective won't do. There is no noun "compatible", much less one defined as "mechanical contraption that can be used as a replacement for an original one".

@FumbleFingers I have to add that the noun is not found in my dictionary (SOED, a shortened version of the OED, of 4000 pages of fine print, fairly complete). If this noun appears in the literature it is in connection with pure concepts and pure science (mathematics, chemistry, and IT) as well as with electrical engineering; here is  the Google page of results for "a compatible is"; it seems  to support this latter fact.

Specifically for medical drugs, the noun generic is used for a no-name, typically cheaper product with the same active ingredients which can simply substituted for the brand name original. Merriam-Webster does not limit the use to drugs, but that is surely most common.

Another term is a drop-in replacement. That implies that one version of a product can be removed and another installed without any adjustments. It's commonly used in software engineering, if one piece of software is replaceable by another without any adaptation.
Dictionary.com:

requiring only insertion to be ready for use: a drop-in battery pack.


Sometimes duplicate is used to describe a product that is supposed to look like an international brand, but isn't.
For example

Billy Cream – Brylcreme
Rollex – Rolex
KatKot – KitKat

Also replica.

Also knock-off.

Analogous is the word that you are looking for, not analogues. For example, the wings of a bird and the wings of an airplane are analogous because they both serve the function of enabling flight, even though they are structurally different.

Rephrasing the sentence to use an adjective isn’t helpful when OP specifically asked for a noun.  Also, “analogue” actually is the correct word, but it’s not widely used in this sense in English outside of specific fields. One field where it is used is in Chemistry, for different molecules that interact in the same way with a specific catalyst or enzyme.
